# Launch external program with string arguments containing line breaks

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process, command-line-arguments

From a `.Net` `WinForms` `C#` application I need to invoke another program (which is also a `.Net` `WinForms` `C#` application if that makes any difference) with string arguments containing line break / new line characters.

If I use `Process.Start()` method (in the **calling program**) and `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` (in the **called program**) to do this, it is equivalent to running the program from the command line. In this case, will be able to pass string arguments containing line break / new line characters without running into issues on either side?

Comment: Look at [Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx) method and the [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class. I believe you should be able to set pretty much whatever you want for `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments`. Perhaps that'll work.

Comment: Perhaps the @ prefix before the string to pass also will help. ( Forgot what it stands for ).

Comment: `Process.Start()` calls `CreateProcess()`. There is no command line interpreter involved. This is not at all the same as running a process from the command line. The command line interpreter imposes restrictions on valid characters in a command line. You cannot pass a newline character through the command line (but you can through a call to `CreateProcess()`).

Comment: @IInspectable: Totally correct. I tried this out in a sample program and inferred the same thing, that `Process.Start()` is not at all the same as invoking a program from the command line. Do you want to post this as the answer, so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Answered By – IInspectable Aug 17 at 16:07`

`Process.Start()` calls `CreateProcess()`. There is no command line interpreter involved. This is not at all the same as running a process from the command line. The command line interpreter imposes restrictions on valid characters in a command line. You cannot pass a newline character through the command line (but you can through a call to `CreateProcess()`).